# Defined size doesn't corespond to real size on the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've encountered curious problem, and I'm wondering what is wrong.

When I define for example Sprite and I draw inside rectangle 20 x 20 px, then when measured on screen it have something like 33 x 33 px, while swf window which was defined as 400 x 300 corresponds to definition well.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that your content is being scaled? I'm assuming you're doing a print screen an measuring it with photoshop or some other program.

If so, give this a try:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but why is it set to behaave like that by default? Is there any other way to supress this behavior for example in html wrapper?

Comment: You can set this in the embed code. The parameter name is `scale` and its value is `noscale`. If you're using swfaddress, it'd be something like this: `so.addParam("scale", "noscale");`